# Two Time htacces Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to do something like this : 
1 Rewrite :

> Force : localhost/main/ ==> localhost

2 Rewrite :

> localhost/?api=test123&page=m1 ==> localhost/test123/m1

and if api is empty , just go page

> localhost/m1 => Page : m1 ( in this url , user don't ask to api )

I have this htaccess :

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !main/
RewriteRule (.*) /main/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main/index.php?api=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

It's the awnser :

```html
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /main/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L] [OR]
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)/$ /main/index.php?api=$1 [QSA,L] [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !main/
RewriteRule (.*) /main/$1
```